# iOS 13's presentationControllerDidDismiss() Not Called for Popover in Compact Environment

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, ios13

I am updating my app for iOS 13’s new “card-style” modal views. All has been working well using `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate`’s `presentationControllerDidAttemptToDismiss()` and `presentationControllerDidDismiss()` functions. But, for views that have their `.modalPresentationStyle` set to `.popover`, `presentationControllerDidDismiss()` is not called when being presented in compact environments (such as a phone or iPad in split or slide-over). It’s called correctly when presented in a regular size class environment (such as an iPad full-screen).

My code setting this up is pretty straightforward:

The code presenting the popover:

```
func showChooser() {
    // other setup code...
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    navController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = self.viewController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
    self.present(navController, animated: true)
}
```

Then, the presented controller conforms to `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` and sets up:

```
// This is in the presented view controller (i.e. the popover)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // other setup removed for brevity…
    self.navigationController?.presentationController?.delegate = self
}

func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
    print("did dismiss")
    self.cancel?()
}
```

When the view is presented in regular size-class environments, it is displayed correctly as a popover. When the user taps outside the popover, then `presentationControllerDidDismiss()` is called. However, when the same code is presented in a compact environment, it’s displayed correctly (as a card style), but when the user drags down the view, `presentationControllerDidDismiss()` is not called.

If I change the `.modalPresentationStyle` to something else such as `.pageSheet` or `.formSheet`, then it all works as expected in either compact or regular presentations.

I’ve tried using the delegate's `adaptivePresentationStyle()` to change the style to `.formSheet` on compact environments, but `presentationControllerDidDismiss()` is still not called correctly.

**Update**:
I should have mentioned that my current workaround is to check the size class and change `.modalPresentationStyle` as needed:

```
if self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic
} else {
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    navController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = self.viewController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
}
```

This works, but it seems that just using the `.popover` style should adapt properly and call the correct delegate methods.

**Update 2:**
I've updated the code above to clarify that the *presented* view controller is the one handling the delegate methods.

Also, after digging into this more, I noticed that if the *presenting* view controller is the delegate and handles the delegate methods, then this all works as expected. Since it also works in the *presented* view controller for all `.modalPresentationStyle`'s *except* popover in compact environments, perhaps there is some lifetime issue when popovers are presented in that way?

Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Good research. One question. How about `willDismiss`? Is that called?

Comment: @matt, no, that is not being called either. The only delegate method that is called in compact environments is `adaptivePreesentationStyle()`.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce this and let you know if I have any thoughts. Again, good research. One more thought in the meantime: observe that the presented view controller really doesn't need to get the `dismiss` delegate methods, because its own `viewDidDisappear` will catch this.

Comment: @matt, I appreciate it. Good point about `viewDidDisappear`. That could work in this case. Now that iOS defaults to this card style modal view, this would also work in other cases since `viewDidDisappear` is no longer called when presenting another modal on top of the current one.

Comment: OK I've given some other workarounds that will cause `will` and `did` to start working as expected. I'm sorry to disappoint you but I don't think we can count this as a bug.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is merely one of timing. You're doing this in the second view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationController?.presentationController?.delegate = self
}
```

That's too *late*. You can set the delegate where you configure and perform the presentation:

```
func showChooser() {
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    navController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = 
        self.viewController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
    navController.presentationController?.delegate = // *
        navController.viewControllers[0] 
        as! UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate
    self.present(navController, animated: true)
}
```

If you prefer to insist upon having the second view controller set itself as delegate, do it earlier. The first good opportunity is `willMove`:

```
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    self.parent?.presentationController?.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @matt. This is very helpful. Setting the delegate before I present the popover works perfectly. I had hoped to have the second view controller do it, but I'll adapt the code to this. I must have just been lucky that the timing works for other modal styles. Also, for some reason, `willMove` is never called on my modal view, but `didMove` is. Setting the delegate in `didMove` does not work, and I assume at that point it's also too late.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Failure to call `willMove` suggests you have a mistake in your other code, such as not calling `super` in some override.

Comment: By the way it isn’t just the modal style, it’s the fact that you’re wrapped in a nav controller. So by the time you get viewDidLoad the presentation is underway.

Comment: Re: `willMove` I thought I'd made sure `super` was called where needed, but I'll check again. Good point about the timing of the presentation in a nav controller. Very helpful discussion.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks heaps for that example - just to extend on the details from Matt and for the benefit of those looking for a generic example (with the creation of a standalone viewController), I believe something like the below should also work:

```
func presentExampleViewController() {
    // Any other setup code specific to the view in your app can go here...
    let exampleViewController = SomeCustomViewController()
    exampleViewController.presentationController?.delegate = exampleViewController
    self.present(exampleViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `navController.presentationController?.delegate = // *
        navController.viewControllers[0]` after `self.present(navController, animated: true)` otherwise your `presentationController` might be nil

Answer (score 0):

if your viewController is nested inside another navigationviewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    presentationController?.delegate = self
}
```